# Create an animated 'stack' via AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, animation

I'm using ASP.NET for a search app web site.

My search retrieves exactly one result per fetch. Once the search is complete and the user selects "Update", a new result is fetched and the old result is written to the ViewState as a generic List. The new result replaces the old one.

I am trying to get the page to update (via partial post-back), so that the old result drops down the screen and the new result sits on top of it. Much like the concept of a stack.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved? I've started looking at the Ajax Control Toolkit.

Would appreciate any hints and tips with regard to my problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JQuery, this sort of things is fairly straightforward.  I would suggest avoiding the partial post-back and using a WebMethod (on a "page method"), then calling that to get the results.  In that scenario, JQuery can manage the request to the server and process the response data exactly how you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a just beginning to play around with AJAX animations, but this reference page has been a big help to me.

[AJAX Animation Reference](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Walkthrough/AnimationReference.aspx#Animation)